# complicated index/match with multiple columns and rows

Tags: excel-formula, lookup

I have a complicated lookup that has 2 criteria, the issue is that the 2nd criteria is dependent on the location of the first and I am having trouble understanding how to feed it the location from the first match.

Criteria 1 is easy it is family size and it basically reads from one column and matches the family size

Criteria 2 is income amount, the income table is 4 columns wide and 8 rows deep (C5:F12). The income amount varies depending on family size. So I need to return the value that closest matches the income for that family size without surpassing the number. IN the example below the income provided is $55,200 for a family size of 4 should return E8 ($62,950).

Once I have that I then have to write another formula to return the award amount which is on row 4. In the example provided the award amount would be cell E4 ($70,000). I have no clue what formula I would use for this; maybe a long IF statement (not sure).

I am using this formula but am getting the #N/A error which is likely because of the size of the lookup array. Every example I’ve seen on index/match has the columns to lookup the value in one row but with my data the row that needs to be looked in is dependent on the family size.

```
=INDEX(C5:F12,MATCH(C14,B5:B12,0),MATCH(C15,C5:F12,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need the intermediate step of finding the amount on the table?  Can the order of the columns be reversed to go from low to high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the intermediate step.  Just use:

```
=INDEX($C$4:$F$4,MATCH($C$15,INDEX($C$5:$F$12,MATCH($C$14,$B$5:$B$12,0),0),-1))
```

[image]

---

If you want the other value put this formula in C17:

```
=INDEX($C$5:$F$12,MATCH($C$14,$B$5:$B$12,0),MATCH($C$15,INDEX($C$5:$F$12,MATCH($C$14,$B$5:$B$12,0),0),-1))
```

[image]

These formula work independent of each other.

Comment: Scott, thanks so much for this formula, no I don't need the intermediate step. I noticed that you did not require the table to be re-arranged from lowest to highest and it still works. The formulas appears so simple but I have to break it down to understand it so I can apply it to a few other scenarios.

Comment: The inner index: `INDEX($C$5:$F$12,MATCH($C$14,$B$5:$B$12,0),0)` return the full row where the match is found.  the `0` in the third criterion tell the formula you want the full row.  So the correct row is returned to the outer Match which in turn returns the correct position to the outer INDEX.

Comment: Remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.